# How to aggregate rows into a json using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

| lat | long | city | nameDisease | numberCases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | rio | Dengue | 1 |
| 0 | 2 | rio | Chicungunha | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | sp | Dengue | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | sp | COVID | 4 |

I want to aggregate the rows with same (lat,long,city) and generate a json as follows:

```
[{lat:0,long:2,city:"rio",diseases:[{nameDisease:"Dengue",numberCases:1},{nameDisease:"Chicungunha",numberCases:2}],{lat:1,long:3,city:"sp",diseases:[{nameDisease:"Dengue",numberCases:3},{nameDisease:"COVID",numberCases:4}]]
```

How can I do this kind of transformation with pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few `to_dict` + `groupby` calls:

```
json = df.groupby(cols).apply(lambda g: g.drop(cols, axis=1).to_dict('records')).reset_index().rename({0:'diseases'}, axis=1).to_dict('records')
```

Output:

```
>>> json
[{'lat': 0,
  'long': 2,
  'city': 'rio',
  'diseases': [{'nameDisease': 'Dengue', 'numberCases': 1},
   {'nameDisease': 'Chicungunha', 'numberCases': 2}]},
 {'lat': 1,
  'long': 3,
  'city': 'sp',
  'diseases': [{'nameDisease': 'Dengue', 'numberCases': 3},
   {'nameDisease': 'COVID', 'numberCases': 4}]}]
   
>>> json == expected_output
True
```